# Adding session_id as a parameter causes me to get a 403 error in Apache/PHP?

Tags: php, apache

I keep getting errors trying to call a URL with a URL parameter called session_id.

https://paystackussd.sitebuilder.com.ng/paystackgame.php?msisdn=2340000006&network=MTN&session_id=1230601&endofsession=false#

If I remove the underscore and put it anywhere else it works.

For example, this works
https://paystackussd.sitebuilder.com.ng/paystackgame.php?msisdn=2340000006&net_work=MTN&sessionid=1230601&endofsession=false#

So does this
https://paystackussd.sitebuilder.com.ng/paystackgame.php?msisdn=2340000006&net_work=MTN&sessionid_=1230601&endofsession=false#

What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

When `session.use_trans_sid` is set to `1` in php.ini, PHP reserves session_id in URL for transferring session ID in URL. You should use another name or disable that feature in php.ini and use cookies for session ID transfer handling which is more secure.

[Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid)